# Security procedures for retrieving/setting passwords and other sensitive data

Tags: c#

I am sure some of you have written C# classes which have to set/get passwords from/to a database.

I would assume the sensitive details wouldn't be in plaintext. What are the recommended procedures for dealing with this sort of data? Is the text encrypted once retrieved? Do you store pws in an .xml file which is encrypted?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- NEVER store passwords in plain text, or at all.   You should instead be storing a hashed version of the (password and salt), using a cryptographic hash function, like SHA-2.
- So 'storing the passwords in an xml file which is encrypted' isn't the right direction - that implies you will be decrypting the file at some point, and therefore have access to all your users passwords (and thus, an attacker would have access to all your users passwords if your system were compromised)  By storing hashes, you won't be able to get to your user's passwords, even if you wanted to.
- So, when a person logs in, you would confirm that the password is correct by hashing the password that the person typed in, and compare it to the hash which you have stored - if the hashes match, the the password is correct.
- Always use a randomly generated [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to make it infeasible for attackers to use  [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_tables) to crack passwords, in the event your stored list of password hashes is compromised.
- Depending on the nature of your application, you should be enforcing [password complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength) rules of some sort.

Comment: In addition: in case you generate passwords randomly and the user cannot change them, do **not** enforce password complexity rules since they will actually **reduce** the number of possible values :)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to store a [salted hash of the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300890) in a database.