# hash password in SQL Server (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, hash, passwords

Is this how hashed password stored in SQL Server should look like?

[alt text http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/2545/88871034.gif](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/2545/88871034.gif)

This is function I use to hash password (I found it in some tutorial)

```
public string EncryptPassword(string password)
{
    //we use codepage 1252 because that is what sql server uses
    byte[] pwdBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(password);
    byte[] hashBytes = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(pwdBytes);
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(hashBytes);
}
```

**EDIT**
I tried to use sha-1 and now strings seem to look like as they are suppose to:

```
public string EncryptPassword(string password)
{
    return FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(password, "sha1");
}

// example output: 39A43BDB7827112409EFED3473F804E9E01DB4A8
```

Result from the image above looks like broken string, but this sha-1 looks normal....

Will this be secure enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your're close, but not quite there.

For a secure hash, you will need a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) value in another column.  Second, try to stay away from MD5 as a hashing provider.  It's not as secure as [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) or SHA-2.  SHA-1 is included in .NET just like MD5 is.

Comment: So, you're saying that this kind of entry looks ok?

Comment: Your sha1 sample looks normal but you should do as Dave says and throw in a salt value as well.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300890/md5-hash-with-salt-for-keeping-password-in-db-in-c