# How authenticate a user using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, authentication

I'm creating a web app with .net using a login for users. After registration the users' data is stored in my local SQL database and the user must be able to log in using these.

Currently I've managed to register users and they can log in when I use a hard coded password and user name but I can't figure out how I can check the user's given credentials and the ones in the database to check if these match.

I did extensive research but didn't find a proper solution but surprisingly could not come up with a working solution.

Here is my current code:

**My users model:**

```
namespace Models
{
    public class Users
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string userName { get; set; }
        public string userPassword { get; set; }
        public string userEmail { get; set; }
        public string userCompany { get; set; }


        public class UsersDBContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
        }


    }
}
```

**My controller**

```
namespace Eindwerk.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private Users.UsersDBContext db = new Users.UsersDBContext();

        // GET: /Users/    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Users users)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(users.userName == "NAAM" && users.userPassword == "WACHTWOORD")
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(users.userName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("", "Home");
                }
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username and/or password");
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

**My View**

```
@model Eindwerk.Models.Users

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "../_Login.cshtml";

}
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="panel-body">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userName, new { @class = "form-control", Value="Username"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userName)
        </div>
                <br />
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userPassword, new { @class = "form-control", Value= "Password"  })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userPassword)
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"/>
        </p>

    </fieldset>
        </div>
}
```

So instead of using  `if(users.userName == "NAAM" && users.userPassword == "WACHTWOORD")`
I want to check properly if the user is valid and registered in my database or not so I can grant or deny access.

Anybody a proper solution? Or link to decent documentation in order to resolve this issue?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Your question is how to send data from view to controller or how to check if that user is already in database?

Comment: Why don't you use asp.net.identity? ? There are allot of templates and tutorial that can save you time

Comment: Never heard of it before actually... I just managed to get my registration/login successful but will definitely take a look at asp.net identity!

Comment: your controller seems to be missing an `else` or remove the unnecessary brackets around `ModelState.AddModelError()`

Comment: Thanks for proposed answers but B2K already provided me with a solid solution to my problem!

Comment: Please do not use that solution. I will post a solution doing things safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the db.Users collection.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Users users)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var hash = GenerateHash(users.userPassword,Settings.Default.salt);
            var authUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(row => row.userName == users.userName && row.userPassword == hash )
            if ( authUser != null )
            {
                Session["role"] = authUser.Role;

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(users.userName, false);
                return RedirectToAction("", "Home");
            }
            else 
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username and/or password");
            }
        }

        return View();
}

private static string GenerateHash(string value, string salt)
{
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt + value);
    data = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create().ComputeHash(data);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);
}
```

See [MD5 hash with salt for keeping password in DB in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300890/md5-hash-with-salt-for-keeping-password-in-db-in-c-sharp) for a more indepth discussion of salting and hashing. Note that I'm assuming you have a Settings class with the salt value. You can replace this with another mechanism for retrieving the salt.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot B2K! Been looking for that all day!

Comment: A side question tough: I want to use 3 roles (Admin, user and editor), how do you give these roles to those registered users?

Comment: Please please please, hash and salt your passwords. the password should **never** exist in your database in plain text!

Comment: @user3629755 Just add another field to Users for the role, and store the role in the user's session. Editing my answer above.

Comment: @mason So, you come along 6 months late to the party and your only contribution is to down vote my response? 

There is already even a comment on the original question suggesting that the user investigate using a more robust authentication scheme. 
I happen to agree with all three of you on that point.

I'll edit my post to demonstrate how to use a one-way encryption scheme. Please remove the down vote.